# How do I get the selected text from a WordEditor Object (in Outlook2010) and Copy it to another Form?

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, outlook-2010

i want to Copy selected Text from WordEditor(Body of Outlook Email) to another Form when i searched i found that part of code to Copy to new Word Document by using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document**

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem;
Outlook.Inspector inspector = mailItem.GetInspector;

// Obtain the Word.Document object from the Inspector object
Word.Document document = (Word.Document)inspector.WordEditor;

// Copy the selected objects
document.Application.Selection.Copy();
```

i always get Error with mailItem.GetInspector part ( Object refrence is not set to instance of object )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to request the active inspector from the `Application` object. [`Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff863939.aspx) will provide you with the currently active inspector reference which you can then request the [`CurrentItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb220040%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and convert to a `MailItem` reference if the item is a `MailItem` type (*could also be a CalendarItem, TaskItem, NoteItem, etc.*).

Comment: can you please complete the above code

Answer (score 2):

for starters you are not using the OutLook.MailItem properly..
use something like this as a test and utilize it and make changes as you see fit to fit your UseCase

```
public void ShowEmail(string To, string Subject, string Body)
{
    Outlook.Application myOutlook = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.NameSpace myNamespace = myOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    myNamespace.Logon(null, null, null, null);
    Outlook.MAPIFolder outbox = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox);
    Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)outbox.Items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

    mail.Recipients.Add(To);
    mail.Subject = Subject;
    mail.Body = Body;

    mail.GetInspector.Activate();
}

Go ahead and test it, create a button on your form and in the Click event handler:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowEmail("youremailOutlookAddress.com", "Hello!", "Hey here's a test Email!");
}
```

[OutLookMailItem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/e1b01b51-dee2-4da9-ad59-7dfb838bfb26) how to use Outlook

Answer (score 0):

Set the MailItem object to "objExplorer.Selection[1] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;" where objExplorer = AddIn name.Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();

Comment: This was how  I got rid of the issue.