# Button in Outlook's MailItem body which would call internal addin function

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in, mailitem

I'm developing an add-in in c# for outlook's 2007 and 2010.

Lets say I have `Outlook.MailItem` object of currently displayed mail and I want to replace part of the mail text with buttons, that would call an internal add-in function (*passing some parameters of course*). Is that even possible to make that callback to add-in function? If yes then could you guys put me on the right track, because I can't seem to find anything related to this.

Comment: Would having a "region" with buttons be sufficient for your use case?  That would mean that there is a bar at the top/bottom of the message that contains the buttons.

Comment: Well it wouldn't be that much user intuitive that I'd like, but if there isn't a proper solution to this, I'l probably make something like this or I make a custom protocol:// with software that handles it, and then insert href's into mail body with appropriate links.

Comment: @VytautasKlumbys, I came across somewhat the same requirement. Do you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you cannot add buttons to the `MailItem.Body`. The best you could do is add items to the [**Ribbon UI**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172.aspx) based upon the message body's content. There are also similar methods using custom [**Task Panes**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [**Form Regions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386301.aspx).

You can [try working with the Word Editor directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8901066/175679), but I have not tried that path.

```cs
Outlook.Inspector inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
Word.Document document = (Word.Document)inspector.WordEditor;
```